# What is the relationship between the edge of a Minkowski sum and the edge of a convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

like this image:

[image]

I know that there is a relationship between the edges of Minkowski and the edges of convex polygons, but I don't know how to describe this relationship mathematically.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is what I know but I don't have a reference: For each convex $n$-gon $A$, let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be its vertices in counterclockwise order and $v_0 = v_n$. Let $E(A) = \{ v_k - v_{k-1} : 1\le k \le n \}$, Given two convex polygons $A$, $B$ where no edge of $A$ is parallel to that of $B$, then $E(A+B) = E(A) \cup E(B)$.

Comment: About Minkowski sum, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3147361) of mine, and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1711168) as well.